# Lusin theorem and axiom of choice

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Is Lusin theorem (measurable function is "nearly" continuous) based on the axiom of choice (not countable)?

Comment: It would be better, if you can add more details to elaborate the problem little more.

Comment: The existence of unmeasurable functions depends on AoC. :)

Comment: Put it another way: could this theorem be proven without (uncounable) AC?

Comment: (My last comment should not be construed as an answer, because Lusin still applies if all functions are measurable, since then all Lusin says is that all functions are nearly continuous.) See this answer to see that "all subsets of $\mathbb R$ are measurable" is consistent with $ZF$ + "dependent choice." https://mathoverflow.net/a/42220/7839